# How to query Data from Database for HTML Table Content

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter as the framework, I use php for the backend and using javascript for the frontend. I have this kind of table in my database called "sales_revenue":

```
|area      |   product    | channel    |  revenue |
| area 1   |   drug a     | hospital   |  1000    |
| area 1   |   drug a     | hospital   |  1000    |
| area 1   |   drug a     | store      |  1000    |
| area 1   |   drug b     | hospital   |  1000    |
```

how to query the data and put them into html table?
I want them grouped by product and also the channel and sum the revenue based on the group. 
I expect the result in html table to be like this:

```
|  channel   |   drug a  | drug b    | 
|  hospital  |   2000    | 1000      |
|  store     |   1000    | 0         |
```

And then convert the revenue into percentage like this:

```
|  channel   |   drug a  | drug b    | 
|  hospital  |   66.67%  |  33.33%   |
|  store     |   100%    | 0%        |
```

I want this last table appear on the web

I have tried to build the query like this:

```
$data = $this->db->like('product','drug a')->group_by('channel')->select_sum('revenue')->select('channel')->get('sales_revenue');
```

but this query only result in the product "drug a" and when there is an empty value the table become error because of the null value.

Comment: How it's going? Do you still needing help?

Comment: Yes I setill need help

Comment: how do you calculate 66.67% and 33.33% values?

Comment: (2000/(2000+1000))*100=66.7%,   (1000/(2000+1000)*100=33.33%

Comment: I still don't get how you calculate. Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: let x = drug a in hospital, y = drug b in hospital => percentage of drug a in hospital is = (x /(x+y))*100, percentage of drug b in hospital is = (y/(x+y))*100